# Use Microsoft Translation Hub with category LAW

Tags: microsoft-translator

IS it possible to use Microsoft Translation API for specific category like `LAW`.

Currently I am training Microsoft Custom Translation Hub to train my own model. While creating project system asked me to provide category (i.e., LAW, Technical, etc.) which means it has already trained model for different category.

Is it possible to use category specific model(Microsoft Trained) of Microsoft Translator through API?

Answer (score 0):

On Translator Hub, the only category that gives different results is "Technology", when translating from English to other languages. All other category selections use the same general-domain system underneath. 
Recommendation is to upgrade to Custom Translator: http://customtranslator.ai.

Comment: Can you please help how I can use "Technology" as a category type in Translator Hub.?